# Testar um novo tema no WordPress sem perder as mudanças do tema anterior

Tags: wordpress, temas

Olá, recentemente criei um blog no wordpress, eu gostei do tema, até alguns dias atrás, mas agora estou começando a achar que ele não está muito com cara de blog. Estou usando o tema oblique. O blog já está no ar, porém, nesse tema eu mudei muita coisa no php diretamente.

Gostaria de saber se eu instalar um outro tema no meu wordpress que já está online, se eu corro o risco de perder o que eu já tenho caso eu queira voltar para o tema anterior. E se eu fizer mudanças para testar no tema novo, como ele salva as mudanças no mesmo banco de dados, se isso vai interferir no tema anterior.

Desde já, agradeço.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Gostaria de saber se eu instalar um outro tema no meu wordpress que já está online, se eu corro o risco de perder o que eu já tenho caso eu queira voltar para o tema anterior*

Não. O WordPress permite que você transite entre temas sem problema nenhum, pressupondo que o mesmo tenha sido desenvolvido seguindo as [as regras gerais do desenvolvimento de temas](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development). O que você pode "perder" são *hardcodes* que você fez direto no tema, como `<h1> Meu Blog lindão </h1>`, mas isso se restaura quando você reativar o seu tema.

Meu conselho é que você considere [*child themes*](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) quando quiser fazer qualquer alteração em um tema, até para mantê-lo coerente com possíveis atualizações. Também, temas servem para alterar a forma de *display* de conteúdo, e não para armazenamento do mesmo. Com isso em mente, seu desenvolvimento vai se tornar mais coerente.

Comment: Ah entendi. No meu caso, eu estou usando o oblique mas não é child theme. Agora, se eu quiser testar um outro tema, eu posso testar o child theme por cima dele? Como faço para saber se o tema que quero é um child theme? Desculpa a demora, estava estudando as possibilidades.

Comment: *Child themes* servem pra que você faça alterações em temas sem que você precise alterar o original. Se você está usando esse oblique, e quer testar outro, basta que você ative o outro. *Child themes* podem ser identificados pelo nome da sua pasta. Se você quer fazer um *child* desse oblique, basta que você crie um tema em uma pasta chamada `oblique-child`

Comment: Entendi, me esclareceu bastante. Obrigada ;)

Answer (score 3):

**Irei dar disponibilizar 2 métodos que penso que sejam adequados à questão:**

**Primeiro Método:**
Existem varias possibilidades que podem ser utilizadas nesse caso, uma delas que poderá ser a mais facil é usar um **plugin**, existem diversos plugins para o efeito de backups, nesses plugins serão enviados para o seu e-mail o backup do seu website como ele está no momento em que é feito o backup, depois caso queira voltar novamente ao tema antigo basta voltar ao backup feito.

**Segundo Método:**
Mas a forma que eu aconselho não é essa, visto que durante o processo de backups pode existir alguns erros, que podem ser devidos a varios motivos. Eu aconselho a um **Backup Manual**, utilizando a ferramenta FTP, por exemplo o programa **Filezilla FTP**, as características do ftp do seu website são disponibilizadas pelo prestador de hospedagem, no seu painel de controlo.
Já dentro do **FTP**, poderá copiar todos os ficheiros e guardar numa pasta no seu computador, ficar com essa mesma pasta guardada. Em seguida poderá mudar o tema, caso queira voltar a trás basta, ir novamente ao FTP e apagar todos os ficheiros e repor todos os ficheiros que estavam na pasta de backup no seu computador.

Estes dois métodos iram guardar nos seus backups as alterações ao tema. quando repor ela mantém essas alterações e não tem nada do tema posterior que colocou.

(Um extra, caso queira pesquisar alguns plugins para este assunto ou outros assuntos, poderá fazê-lo em [WordPress Plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/)).

Espero ter ajudado. *Cumprimentos.*